# Adobe touch apps What Technology has been used?

Tags: air, flash-builder

Adobe touch apps What Technology has been used ? Is that AIR ? 
http://www.adobe.com/products/touchapps.html

If yes then why People don't like AIR For Mobile Apps ? I don't think you can get something like "Adobe Ideas" App even if you used the IOS Native Lang 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-ideas-1-0-for-ipad/id364617858?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Ideas doesn't show up in Adobe Scout, so my best guess is they are actually native apps. Adobe has never really pushed the AIR platform themselves, honestly. All of their apps are written in native code; even Scout itself which is nothing more than a Flash profiler on steriods is written natively as far as I am aware.